# How do I stop these PG::ProtocolViolation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My method is:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_matching_batteries
    unless inactive?
      update_column :battery_id, nil unless battery
      @battery = Battery.where(:review_id => review.id, :question_id => question.id).first_or_create
      @battery.surveys << self
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `@survey.create_matching_batteries`, I get this:

```
Survey Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "surveys".* FROM "surveys" WHERE "surveys"."competitor_id" = $1 AND "surveys"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["competitor_id", 248], ["id", 15183]]
D, [2014-01-21T22:28:08.830446 #3392] DEBUG -- :   Survey Load (5.2ms)  SELECT "surveys".* FROM "surveys" WHERE "surveys"."competitor_id" = $1 AND "surveys"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["competitor_id", 248], ["id", 15183]]
PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "a15" requires 1
: SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys"  WHERE "surveys"."competitor_id" = $1 AND "surveys"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
E, [2014-01-21T22:28:08.830528 #3392] ERROR -- : PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "a15" requires 1
: SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys"  WHERE "surveys"."competitor_id" = $1 AND "surveys"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2014-01-21T22:28:08.833655 #3392] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "a15" requires 1
: SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys"  WHERE "surveys"."competitor_id" = $1 AND "surveys"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
from /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:786:in `get_last_result'
```

In "Railspeak" not "Postgrespeak", what does `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "a15" requires 1` mean? And how can it help me to debug my method?

My environment:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.1
```

Comment: In "postgresspeak" (this is tagged `postgresql`, so you should really expect that): You repeat the same bind parameter placeholder `$1` twice, instead of using separate placeholders `$1` and `$2`. Look at the generated query text. As for why that happens, I'm blissfully unaware of the guts of how Rails works, and will let someone else deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Prepared Statements

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  prepared_statements: false
```

checkout http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: In my case, the problem was using the `activerecord_any_of` gem after upgrading to Rails 4.2. It was now generating invalid PG SQL (making queries with $1, $2 etc. but was not specifying their values at the end of the query). I simply removed that Ruby gem and used Arel table queries, and all is fine.

Bottom-line: I don't think your answer is a good way of going about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, but after counter checking my code, I found out that I had used the same variables in two different fields that is, I had written `fieldA=$2` and also `fieldB=$2`. After correction everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I used quotes around variable

```
quiz_subject = subject_id WHERE subject_name = '$1';
```

I removed those quotes

```
quiz_subject = subject_id WHERE subject_name = $1;
```